# Surface areas of two cubes

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces

> There are two cubes. The points $P$ and $Q$ are both on the small cube: $P$ is a point in the centre of one of the faces, and $Q$ is a corner on the opposite face.
>
> The second cube has sides of length $|PQ|$. What is the surface area of the large cube divided by the surface area of the smaller cube?

I drew both of them and know that the SA of the large cube is $6{QP}$. My problem is with the small cube. In the small cube, if I would connect points $P$ and $Q$, they would for a right angled triangle and line $PQ$ is the hypotenuse. However what is the purpose of this line, how can we find the SA using this?

Comment: What do you mean by SA ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Surface Area? Just guessing…

Comment: @MvG Good guess, ...

Comment: I have proposed a real title (consider that a title with "help" is not very informative for us: everybody here asking a question desires some kind of  help :)

Comment: yes SA is surface area :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The area' ratio $R$ is the square of the length's ratio $r$.
Consider that the cube has sidelength 1.

Let $P'$ be the center of the opposite face of $P$. It is clearly the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto this face. Thus, triangle $PP'Q$ is rectangle in $P'$ with $PP'=1$ and $P'Q=\sqrt{2}/2$ (remember that the diagonal of a square with side 1 is $\sqrt{2}$).

Pythagoras' theorem, applied to triangle $PP'Q$ gives:

$PQ^2=1^2+(\sqrt{2}/2)^2=3/2$. Thus $PQ=\sqrt{3/2}$, giving $r=PQ/1=\sqrt{3/2}$.

Therefore, the ratio of lengths is $r=\sqrt{3/2}/1=\sqrt{3/2}$

Thus the ratio of areas is the square of the previous ratio : $R=r^2=3/2.$

Comment: I completely did not understad what you said.

Comment: I know P' is P on the other side of the cube, however what is PP'?? If you do not mind, may you please draw it?

Comment: Also, I tried doing it by drawing triangle PP'Q, with the right angle being at P'. Then distance between P and P' is 1 and distance from P' to Q is 1/2 because its in the center, using pythagorean therom, I got PQ to be sqrt5 /2

Comment: P' is in the center of the opposite face, thus in the middle of the diagonal. P'Q is thus the half of the diagonal, i.e., $\sqrt{2}$, giving $\sqrt{2}/2$, not $1/2.$

Comment: i got that sqrt (3/2) is length PQ, however I do not understand what you did after that. The question asks for the surafec area of large cube / the small one. I got that the surface area of the large one is 9, and the small one is 1, so how does that work?? What did u do with the ratio? and where did u get it from

Comment: plz help me solve this question as i dont understand it

Comment: I have added a figure. Wish it helps.

Comment: thank u for the figure, i understand everything about it. however what i dont get is why u sqaured the length while they were asking for the the surface are of the large cube/ the small cube

Comment: please read the comment above

Comment: I need an answer quick plzz.... i have drawn the exact same figure, howevr i do not know what u mean by ratio. how can i do it without the ratio???

Comment: surface are of large cube=9, small= 1/

Comment: Have a look at the new figure in my answer.

Comment: thank u. i completely get what ur saying and oind. by question is why is the thing im doing wrong? why is it wrong to simple divide tha areas

Comment: I have added the (red) cube. And I have placed a side of the black cube symbolically inside a side of the black cube: you see that if a side is 1 and the other side PQ=\sqrt{3/2}, the ratio of the areas is the square of the ratio of the sides i.e., $3/2$.

Comment: In my opinion, you were not considering the right cube.

Comment: what do u mean ??????????

Answer (score 1):

Take the cube $[0,1]^3$ as small cube for example (without loss of generality as you may pick your coordinate system any way you want for this task). It has surface area $6$ as its six sides have area $1$ each. Pick e.g. $Q=(0,0,0)$ and $P=(1,\frac12,\frac12)$. Then the distance is $$\lvert P-Q\rvert=\sqrt{1+\frac14+\frac14}=\sqrt{\frac32}$$ So the surface area of the large cube is $6\cdot\frac32=9$ and the quotient between these suface areas is $$\frac96=\frac32$$